# Update redux state with an input

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, redux

How can I update redux's state from a text input?

I'm trying to do a very simple "Hello World" with a text input. When someone types into the text input, it should update my store's "searchTerm" value.

I can't figure out these things:
 1. How can I get and pass the input's value into it's "onChange" handler?
 2. The "search" action seems to be called correctly, but my reducer function is never used (no console.log).

**SearchForm.js** (component)

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {search} from 'redux/modules/search-term';

@connect(
  null,
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({ search }, dispatch)
)

export default class SearchForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    search: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={search} />
    );
  }
}
```

**search-term.js** (action & reducer)

```
const SEARCH = 'redux-example/repo-filter/SEARCH';

const initialState = {
  searchTerm: null
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  console.log("reducing");

  switch (action.type) {
    case SEARCH:
      return {
        searchTerm: action.term
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export function search(term) {
  return {
    type: SEARCH,
    term
  };
}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import multireducer from 'multireducer';
import { routerStateReducer } from 'redux-router';

import search from './search-term';

export default combineReducers({
  router: routerStateReducer,
  search
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `this.props.search` when binding the action creator to the change event:

`<input type="text" placeholder="Search" onChange={(event) => this.props.search(event.target.value)} />`

Comment: awesome trying this now