# React Native Redux Multi Form / Text Input

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am newbie in react native. So i need your help right now. Can you show me some source code about handling multiform in react native? In redux surely. I have added one more parameters in actions, reducers and the component but still not working.

Comment: this is a topic which is explained in a lot of websites with a simple search. Please use the search before asking a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update redux state with an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474272/update-redux-state-with-an-input)

Comment: could you show me the url? i just tried using one form and it works. but i want to add one more parameters in the same action but it doesn't work sir. i have searched for 2 hours about this. i can't find the example

Comment: @EnriqueDev i've tried single input like that. thanks btw, but i don't know update redux state with multi input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a topic so widely documented that should not be asked here, but since you have take a look at:

https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/adding-a-robust-form-validation-to-react-redux-apps-616ca240c124

https://hackernoon.com/using-forms-in-react-redux-tips-and-tricks-48ad9c7522f6

https://x-team.com/blog/tutorial-forms-in-react-and-redux/

Even though hey are for react all the concepts are appliable.
Please, this is just the first results of a google search, use it.

Comment: i'm so sorry sir sir